# Safe sequences for external tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

Goal:

I'm looking for a stable and cheap way to find specific rows in large external tables, specifically for using Snowflake, where the external files can only be read, but not modified (delivered as-is on storage).

Pratical example:

A large XML archive used to keep historic logs. The XMLs are highly variable, and commonly larger then the LOB size. A solution for this is using external tables, which allow larger field contents.

But this imposes another problem.

How can one efficiently find the full content back, in order to do addtional xml parsing of specific records, without fully parsing the entire external files again?

- For copied tables, one can use both the metadata&filename and metadata&row_number.
- For external tables only the metadata&filename is available.

In SQL terms i seek to join materialized views back to the external table in order to do additional processing.

I've looked at sequences to the external table, but these appear to be unstable. An alternative is reparsing the files and joining on the IDs they contain, but this feels like an expensive workaround.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE sequence raw_messages_external_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_messages_external
WITH LOCATION = @messagestore
PATTERN = '100M Gzip/.*.gz'
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE=XML STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT=TRUE);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MESSAGES_VIEW
AS
SELECT 
    -- find original UUID
    value:"@" as message_type, 
    get(split(message_type,':'), 0) as type,
    regexp_substr(type, '\\D+') as type_group, 
    case when type = 'rsm' 
    then get(XMLGET(XMLGET(value, concat(type,':HeaderDocument'), 0), concat(type,':Identification'), 0 ),'$')
    else get(XMLGET(XMLGET(value, concat(type,':HeaderMessage'), 0), concat(type,':MessageId'), 0 ),'$')
    end as XML_ID,
    -- Lookup
    metadata$filename as filename,
    --metadata$file_row_number as row_id,
    --raw_messages_external_seq.nextval,
    row_number() over (partition by filenumber order by value) as file_row_number,
    value as XML_content
FROM raw_messages_external 

CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW MESSAGES_VIEW_STABLE
AS
SELECT 
    -- find original UUID
    value:"@" as message_type, 
    get(split(message_type,':'), 0) as type,
    regexp_substr(type, '\\D+') as type_group, 
    case when type = 'rsm' 
    then get(XMLGET(XMLGET(value, concat(type,':HeaderDocument'), 0), concat(type,':Identification'), 0 ),'$')
    else get(XMLGET(XMLGET(value, concat(type,':HeaderMessage'), 0), concat(type,':MessageId'), 0 ),'$')
    end as XML_ID,
    -- for lookup
    metadata$filename as filename,
    --metadata$file_row_number as row_id,
    --raw_messages_external_seq.nextval,
    row_number() over (partition by filenumber order by value) as file_row_number
FROM raw_messages_external
```

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just load the data into Snowflake and remove the files from storage?  The cost to store them inside Snowflake is likely about the same as storing them on blob storage.

Comment: @MikeWalton, "The XMLs are commonly larger then the LOB size". They can have huge lines, longer than 16mb. So,alas, it is impossible to store the XML's in Snowflake due to the LOB size limit.

Comment: Interesting.  In your view, you have the full 'value' field being returned from the external table.  Can you materialized that or does the 16MB size limit create an error?  This would avoid the need to go back to the full ET to query additional variables.